# How can I generate file preview thumbnails in my desktop application?

Tags: windows, macos, graphics, core-graphics, file-browser

I am developing a sort of file browser on the Mac, and I'm not sure how I can dynamically generate thumbnail previews of files. I would like to do this not just for images, but for common document formats, html, videos, etc., just like in Finder. Is there a built-in API for this, or would I have to search for an external library?

Also, how would I go about doing this on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

i use [geektool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/fr/geektool/) on mac to generate thumbnal previews for images and files, but i don't know witch library use